# Is there a GBA Emulator for Mac OS X Lion?

Tags: macos, game-boy-advance

Can't find an GBA Emulator which doesn't require PowerPC, except NoCashGBA - which sucks. Does anyone know of any other solution?

I want to play Pokemon...

Comment: The [FAQ] specifically prohibits recommendation questions of all kinds.  Off topic.

Comment: PS: Nowadays you can play Pokemon GBA online on any OS, for example: http://emulator.online/tags/pokemon/#gameboy on Google there are dozen of online emulators.

Answer (score 4):

I use [VisualBoyAdvance](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/10123/visualboyadvance) on my Mac, and it works great. It has a bunch of nice features, like state saving, fast-forwarding (for skipping through abysmally long dialogue segments), and video filters.

After realizing VisualBoyAdvance was actually PowerPC-based (which for some reason I never noticed), I did a little more researching. I found this application called [Mac Boy Advance](http://sourceforge.net/projects/macboyadvance/), which is essentially VisualBoyAdvance, but works on Intel-based OS X computers. I successfully ran it on Lion, so it seems to work fine.